# How to reverse the order of displaying content of a list?

Tags: c#, list

Let's say I have a list of integers.

```
var myList = new List<int>();
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 10
```

Is there any function that allows me to display them in reverse order, i.e.

```
10, 9, 8, ..., 1
```

EDIT

---

```
public List<Location> SetHierarchyOfLocation(Location location)
    {
        var list = new List<Location>(7);
        var juridiction = location.Juridiction;
        if (juridiction > 0)
        {
            while (juridiction > 0)
            {
                var loc = repository.GetLocationByID(juridiction);
                list.Add(loc);
                juridiction = loc.Juridiction;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Since the list contains location by location, I want to be able to display it by reversed order as well.

Now, when I write return **list.Reversed()**, I get the error.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`var reversed = myList.Reverse()` should do the trick.

EDIT:

Correction- as the OP found out, List.Reverse works in-place, unlike Enumerable.Reverse.  Thus, the answer is simply `myList.Reverse();` - you don't assign it to a new variable.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "...Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable..."

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that there is a List.Reverse- my example assumed an IEnumerable.  Thats quite confusing actually- Enumerable.Reverse (the extension method) returns the reversed enumeration.  List.Reverse reverses the elements in-place, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Someone downvoted my answer.  If there is something wrong with it, I'd like to know why and correct it, but as soon as you mentioned the error I adjusted it accordingly.  I am fairly sure it is correct now.

Comment: I over simplified my question, see now the whole code. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any function that allows me to display them in reverse order, i.e.

It depends if you want to reverse them in place, or merely produce a sequence of values that is the reverse of the underlying sequence without altering the list in place.

If the former, just use `List<T>.Reverse`.

```
// myList is List<int>
myList.Reverse();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myList));
```

If the latter, the key is [`Enumerable.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx):

```
// myList is List<int>

Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(
        ", ", 
       myList.AsEnumerable().Reverse()
    )
);
```

for a beautiful one-liner. Be sure you have `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "...Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable..."

Comment: I don't think you are since I am not assigning to any implictly-typed local variables. Please try again. Please note that I provided two ways. One uses `List<T>.Reverse`, the other uses `Enumerable.Reverse`.

Comment: You can also use the syntax `myList.AsEnumerable().Reverse()`.

Answer (score -1):

To do a foreach loop in a List`<Location>` reversely you should use:

```
foreach (Location item in myList.Reverse().ToList())
{
   // do something ...
}
```

The .Reverse() is an in-place reverse; it doesn't return a new list. The .ToList() after the .Reverse() do the trick.

Comment: The `ToList` won't even compile, specifically because it is an in place reverse.  It returns `void`.